# Restoring an Archived Project in Project Server 2010?

Tags: project-server, ms-project-server-2010

A project was recently deleted from the Draft and Published databases by mistake. Sever versions are still listed in the Archive database. How can I restore that project to the published database and make it available in PWA?

I tried restoring the project via Administrative Restore. I got a message saying the restore job would be queued. I checked the queue and the job finished successfully - but the project does not appear in Project Center. I'm wondering if Administrative Restore is only meant for restoring specific versions of projects that are still "live".

Thanks for any help and please ask if more information might help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if the project is accessible through Project Professional?  Also, have you checked the simple things that are easy to forget, such as making sure that "sub projects" is selected in the ribbon, or that when you restored, it wasn't marked as closed, and then being excluded from the views?  When I have restored a project previously, sometimes key pieces of Project Details are either missing or incorrect and the project does not appear as expected in the views.  Once the project is opened, the details can be reapplied and the project appears in PWA as expected.

You could also attempt to use "ProjTool."  It would be worth trying to see if that program recognizes it is as available and publish from there.